# A deftemplate code in Jess programing

Tags: jess

I saw such code in a paper:

```
(import com.psy.entity.Record)
```

Can this statement import a Java class?

```
(deftemplate Record(declare(from-class Record)))
```

I don't understand this statement, how to use the declare statement, is there a function in Jess named from-class, I think I have never seen such function in the book of Jess in Action.

```
(defrule show-test-result-20
?0<-(Record {score<=30}))
```

I think it's better to do this test by the test conditional element, is this code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can...class?" -> Yes, that's why you have the import statement. See the Jess manual.

```
(deftemplate Record (declare (from-class Record)))
```

This declares a fact type `Record` as a *shadow fact* for class `Record*. This is discussed and explained in the Jess manual.

"I think...?" -> No, the rule is perfectly all right and preferable.

Comment: Thanks, can you send a Jess manual or other materials for studying Jess to my mail box: dor22@qq.com, I don't have one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See www.jessrules.com .